# Blending two background images in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

is it possible to have two background images in HTML that blends as you scroll down the page?

Basically I have 2 identical images but one is shot in daylight where the other one is shot at night, I want it where the light one is the original image and as the page is scrolled down its starts to blend into the darker one?

Many Thanks in Advance.

Jordan.

Comment: Not with CSS I think. JS could probably manage an opacity transition though.

Comment: Yes. I thought opacity was the way to go,

Comment: Opacity is your style, but you will need JS to listen for the scroll event.

Comment: You can declare multiple background images with css3: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ Any blending would have to be done with the images themselves in that situation, of course (which may lead you to consider just having one image that you blended already in your image editing software.)

Answer (score 0):

it might not be exactly straightforward but might do the trick.

use 2 divs with absolute positioning at give them a negative z-index and 100% widths and heights. This will become the background for website. If you want it to go from day to night give the z-index of the div with the night background a lower number than that of the div with the day background. this way the 'day' div is on top of the 'night' div and it fully covers it.

Now as you scroll down use a javascript logic to check whether a certain amount of pixels has been scrolled and you could reduce the opacity of the 'day' div by, say, 0.1 every 100 pixels or so.

this way, when the user scrolls down by a 1000 pixels, the 'day' div will completely disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest solution is to just do this in your image editing software ahead of time. Blend the two images into one tall image and use that as your background image. It will be a huge image, but still not as big as loading two separate huge images.

Answer (score 0):

Place the day image above night image using absolute positioning. Otherwise use `position:fixed` if you want other content to scroll over the top as the background fades from day to night.

**JavaScript**

```
var start = 500 // how far the user has to scroll down before it start fading
var end = 1200 // the number of pixels the user has to scroll down before the opacity is 0.

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if(scrollTop>start){
        $('.imageDay').css({'opacity':(end-scrollTop)/(end-start)});
    }
});
```

I assume you can work out the html and css.

Answer (score 0):

see this page: [link](http://aveabogados.com/) you can use javascript with jquery like this:

```
/**
 * Parallax Scrolling Tutorial
 * For NetTuts+
 *  
 * Author: Mohiuddin Parekh
 *  http://www.mohi.me
 *  @mohiuddinparekh   
 */


$(document).ready(function(){
    // Cache the Window object
    $window = $(window);

   $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
     var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object

      $(window).scroll(function() {

        // Scroll the background at var speed
        // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                              
        var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

        // Put together our final background position
        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

        // Move the background
        $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

}); // window scroll Ends

 });    

}); 
/* 
 * Create HTML5 elements for IE's sake
 */

document.createElement("article");
document.createElement("section");
```